# "Mimili läuft in den Garten." - shouldn't it be "dem"?

Tags: gender, article, grammatical-number

This is a sentence from children’s book I’m working through:

> Mimili läuft in den Garten.

*Garten* is masculine dative here. So shouldn’t it be *dem?*  Or is *Garten* plural here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural of *Garten* ist *Gärten.* That means *Garten* in this sentence is in the accusative. *In* is a two-way preposition; since it’s in the accusative, that indicates movement. This sentence means:

> Mimili runs into the garden.

Comment: Ah ok.  I had never heard of two-way prepositions before.  Now I understand.  Thanks! :)

Comment: If you're still looking for information on 2way prepositions: http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Praepositionen/Prepositions.html

Comment: Edited "walk" to "run", because the translation of "laufen" as "walk" is only true in some particular regions of Germany and simply wrong everywhere else.

Comment: @Phira Are you sure your "everywhere else" is not limited to Austria and Southern Germany? I think your edit changes the meaning too much.

Comment: Also als ich noch im Rheinland von der Arbeit nach Hause lief anstatt den Bus zu nehmen, rannte ich in der Regel nicht. @Phira

Comment: @arne.b: Especially (?) in South-Western Germany, *laufen* means *to walk*. At least here, we are taught that in standard German, *laufen* means something more akin to *to run*.

Answer (score 8):

No. The issue is with the assumption that Garten is in the dative.

*Mimili läuft in dem Garten* == "Mimili is running in the garden." (and is arguably not very correct German)

*Mimili läuft in den Garten* == "Mimili is running into the garden." (accusative)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first sentence, even if most of the time one would contract "in dem" to "im" if one would not want to put special emphasis "dem".